# How to set UIBarButtonItem Image on click three tier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Hi there my current code is as follows and i would like to know how to implement a button icon change within my current if statement if possible if this is not possible then what code will i need to use instead? Many thanks in advance.

viewController.m

```
   #import "GroupsViewController.h"
    #import "CustomCell.h"

    @interface GroupsViewController ()
    {
        NSArray *arrayOfImages;
        NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
    }

    @end

    @implementation GroupsViewController
    {
        NSString *reuseIdentifier;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
        [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDelegate:self];
        reuseIdentifier= @"SmallIcon";

        arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"?.png", nil];

        arrayOfDescriptions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"?", nil];

    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
    }

    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [[cell IconImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
        [[cell IconLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

- (IBAction)cellToggleAction:(id)sender {

    if([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SmallIcon"]){
        reuseIdentifier=@"ListView";
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scion.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if
        ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ListView"]){
        reuseIdentifier=@"LargeIcon";
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"subaru.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if
        ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"LargeIcon"]){
        reuseIdentifier=@"SmallIcon";
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lotus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [self.GroupsCollectionView reloadData];
}

    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        CGSize cellSize;

        if([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SmallIcon"])
            cellSize = CGSizeMake(100, 130);
        else if
            ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ListView"])
            cellSize = CGSizeMake(320, 130);
        else if
            ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"LargeIcon"])
            cellSize = CGSizeMake(320, 350);

        return cellSize;
    }
    @end
```

After implementing your current suggestions i receive the following error message:

```
[UIBarButtonItem setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
As it turns out **sender** is an instance of [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:)

For this class use the method `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` in replace of `setImage:forState:` as in the original post below which is for a **UIButton**. Also typecast **sender** to **UIBarButtonItem**

```
[(UIBarButtonItem*)sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scion.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**
*Assuming* **(id)sender** is the **UIButton** instance you want to change in the method named `-cellToggleAction:(id)sender`, typecast **sender** to a **UIButton** and then call `-setImage:forState:` on it in the if statement.

Alternatively you could change the above mentioned method to have an argument of type **UIButton** rather than **id**, so as to avoid the typecast and it also makes the code more readable.

an example could be -

```
- (IBAction)cellToggleAction:(UIButton*)sender {

if([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SmallIcon"]) {
    reuseIdentifier=@"ListView";
    [sender setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];// may need other states configured
}
else if .. // continue similarly
```

Comment: I have implemented my current code as per your suggestion and i receive and error messaged on the edited version of my post, Tanks in advance for any help

Comment: @LeeSugden the reason for the error is that UIBarButtonItem is not a UIButton. They are different classes, however the same principal applies but you just need to call a different method (selector). See my edit.